# Want to use a recycler view in a fragment. Created an adapter when I set the adapter it shows me error

Tags: java, android

I want to build an app by which I can generate bussiness card. So I use navigaion drawer. For navigating menus I use fragment class for each of the menus and corresponding XML layout. In one of the layout I want to show my card view inside recyclerview.

MycardFragment.java
(This is the fragment class where I want show recyclerview)

```
package com.example.look.np.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.look.np.R;
import com.example.look.np.models.Template;
import com.example.look.np.utils.FirebaseMethod;
import com.example.look.np.utils.RecyclerviewAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyCardFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MyCardFragment";

    private Context mContext;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef ;
    List<Template> listdata;

    public MyCardFragment() {
       // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //i tried this section but it gimes me error
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext=context;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable      ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mycards,container,false);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("template");

        // Initialize Template Model Class
        Template template = new Template();

        // ...
        // Lookup the Recycler view in fragment layout
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
        RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(template,inflater.getContext());//>>>This is the error i'm facig
        // Set layout manager to position the items
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                listdata = new ArrayList<Template>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.child("template").getChildren()){

                    Template value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Template.class);
                    Template fire = new Template();

                    String name = value.getP_name();
                    String desig = value.getP_designation();
                    String email = value.getP_email();
                    String phone = value.getP_phone();
                    String address = value.getC_address();
                    String c_name = value.getC_name();

                    fire.setP_name(name);
                    fire.setP_designation(desig);
                    fire.setP_email(email);
                    fire.setP_phone(phone);
                    fire.setC_name(c_name);
                    fire.setC_address(address);

                    listdata.add(fire);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("Hello", "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

I aslo created an adapter for recycler view, when I want to set the adapter to the fragment class it shows error. It takes context and List. For context I add getActivity() bMycardFragment.java
(This is the fragment class where I want show recyclerview)

```
package com.example.look.np.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.look.np.R;
import com.example.look.np.models.Template;
import com.example.look.np.utils.FirebaseMethod;
import com.example.look.np.utils.RecyclerviewAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyCardFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MyCardFragment";

    private Context mContext;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef ;
    List<Template> listdata;

    public MyCardFragment() {
       // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //i tried this section but it gimes me error
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext=context;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable      ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mycards,container,false);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("template");

        // Initialize Template Model Class
        Template template = new Template();

        // ...
        // Lookup the Recycler view in fragment layout
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
        RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(template,inflater.getContext());//>>>This is the error i'm facig
        // Set layout manager to position the items
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                listdata = new ArrayList<Template>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.child("template").getChildren()){

                    Template value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Template.class);
                    Template fire = new Template();

                    String name = value.getP_name();
                    String desig = value.getP_designation();
                    String email = value.getP_email();
                    String phone = value.getP_phone();
                    String address = value.getC_address();
                    String c_name = value.getC_name();

                    fire.setP_name(name);
                    fire.setP_designation(desig);
                    fire.setP_email(email);
                    fire.setP_phone(phone);
                    fire.setC_name(c_name);
                    fire.setC_address(address);

                    listdata.add(fire);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("Hello", "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

MycardFragment.java
(This is the fragment class where I want show recyclerview)

```
package com.example.look.np.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.look.np.R;
import com.example.look.np.models.Template;
import com.example.look.np.utils.FirebaseMethod;
import com.example.look.np.utils.RecyclerviewAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyCardFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MyCardFragment";

    private Context mContext;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef ;
    List<Template> listdata;

    public MyCardFragment() {
       // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //i tried this section but it gimes me error
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext=context;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable      ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mycards,container,false);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("template");

        // Initialize Template Model Class
        Template template = new Template();

        // ...
        // Lookup the Recycler view in fragment layout
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
        RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(template,inflater.getContext());//>>>This is the error i'm facig
        // Set layout manager to position the items
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                listdata = new ArrayList<Template>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.child("template").getChildren()){

                    Template value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Template.class);
                    Template fire = new Template();

                    String name = value.getP_name();
                    String desig = value.getP_designation();
                    String email = value.getP_email();
                    String phone = value.getP_phone();
                    String address = value.getC_address();
                    String c_name = value.getC_name();

                    fire.setP_name(name);
                    fire.setP_designation(desig);
                    fire.setP_email(email);
                    fire.setP_phone(phone);
                    fire.setC_name(c_name);
                    fire.setC_address(address);

                    listdata.add(fire);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("Hello", "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

I have an adapter class which takes context and List of items. Now I want to set my adapter in a fragment by passing context (getActivity() and List but it shows me error

```
    I tried getActivity() but it  show me error
    i also tried this
      @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            mContext=context;
        }





    //This is adapter class for my Recyclerview
    RecyclerAdater.java

package com.example.look.np.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.look.np.R;
import com.example.look.np.models.Template;

import java.util.List;


public class RecyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.MyHolder>{

    // ... constructor and member variables

    // Usually involves inflating a layout from XML and returning the holder
    List<Template> listdata;
    Context context;

    public RecyclerviewAdapter(List<Template> listdata, Context context) {
        this.listdata = listdata;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        MyHolder myHolder = new MyHolder(view);
        return myHolder;
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

        Template data = listdata.get(position);
        holder.pname.setText(data.getP_name());
        holder.pdesignation.setText(data.getP_designation());
        holder.pemail.setText(data.getP_email());
        holder.pphone.setText(data.getP_phone());
        holder.cname.setText(data.getC_name());
        holder.caddress.setText(data.getC_address());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //return listdata.size();
        int arr = 0;

        try{
            if(listdata.size()==0){
                arr = 0;
            }
            else{
                arr=listdata.size();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arr;

    }


    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        // Your holder should contain a member variable
        // for any view that will be set as you render a row
        TextView pname,caddress,pemail,pdesignation,pphone,cname;

        // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
        // and does the view lookups to find each subview

        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
            // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
            super(itemView);

            pname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_personName);
            caddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_address);
            pemail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
            pdesignation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_designation);
            pphone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_phone);
            cname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_companyName);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point to be noted, don't forget to set `layoutManager` to `recyclerview` and to set `adapter`.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);

recyclerviewAdapter adapter = new recyclerviewAdapterAdapter(listdata,getActivity());        

recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Another thing to notice in your code is:
There is network call (Which run in background) in `oncreateView()`. Before it gives result, the return view; is getting called.

This means the view is not updated while on background job is going.

This can be resolved by calling separate method like `setRecyclerView()` from `onCreateView()` method. After getting result from background operation you can set your recyclerview as mentioned above.

Don't forget to call the `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` method.

Comment: Thank you,sir. I have another question if you have time please feel free to answer
Question: Is it possible to pass multiple card view layout in a Recycler view?
N.B: In recyclerview, i want to add different design from different cardview

Comment: Rather than passing multiple card view, you can achieve this by doing the following.

Include all card view in one recyclerview item. 
Your list should have some field which decides which card view to be displayed in the recycler view. Make other recycler view Visibility GONE.

Comment: Thanks sir, Can you give me an example or any helpful link to achieve this goal ?